# User select which excel sheet to be loaded in C#

Tags: c#, excel, database, ms-access, user-controls

I want to read an **excel** file. This excel file have multiple **sheets**. The user have the choice to select which **sheet** is loaded in c# to work with it. I want to copy data into access database.

I have written the code for loading excel workbook and for copying data into access database table. But in this code only user select the Excel file not the worksheet, i have hard coded the worksheet name **`Seven`** in code.

> **How to give functionality for user to select his own choice sheet in
> workbook excel. Also i want to retrieve all worksheets in excel file.**

Code is under

```
private void btnImport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var openFileExcel = new OpenFileDialog()
        {
            Filter = "Excel Files | *.xlsx; *.xls; *.xlsm",
            Title = "Select an Excel File",
            CheckFileExists = true
        };
        if (openFileExcel.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.Cancel)
            return;
        DatabaseObjects.FileName = openFileExcel.FileName;
        using(OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(DatabaseObjects.ConnectionString), 
            connExcel = new OleDbConnection(DatabaseObjects.ConnectionStringExcel))
        {
            string query = "INSERT INTO Students (RollNo, SName, FName, ClassID) VALUES(@RollNo, @SName, @FName, @ClassID)";
            string queryExcel = "SELECT * FROM [Seven$]";
            using (OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(query, conn), commandExcel = new OleDbCommand(queryExcel,connExcel))
            {
                OleDbParameter param1 = new OleDbParameter("RollNo", OleDbType.Numeric);
                command.Parameters.Add(param1);
                OleDbParameter param2 = new OleDbParameter("SName", OleDbType.VarChar);
                command.Parameters.Add(param2);
                OleDbParameter param3 = new OleDbParameter("FName", OleDbType.VarChar);
                command.Parameters.Add(param3);
                OleDbParameter param4 = new OleDbParameter("ClassID", OleDbType.Numeric);
                command.Parameters.Add(param4);
                conn.Open();
                connExcel.Open();
                OleDbDataReader drExcel = commandExcel.ExecuteReader();
                while(drExcel.Read())
                {
                    param1.Value = Convert.ToInt32(drExcel[0]);
                    param2.Value = drExcel[1].ToString();
                    param3.Value = drExcel[2].ToString();
                    param4.Value = Convert.ToInt32(drExcel[4]);
                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm using the office interop classes to retrieve sheets names in excel file

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application xlApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook excelBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("D:\\Book1.xlsx"); 
    
    String[] excelSheets = new String[excelBook.Worksheets.Count];
    int i = 0;
    foreach(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet wSheet in excelBook.Worksheets)    
    {
      excelSheets[i] = wSheet.Name;
      i++;
    }
```

Comment: I can get the sheets. But how the user of application knows to select the sheet, who is just using the interface not the coding part?

Comment: add sheet name to combobox/list control , in your btnImport_Click event just change the sheet name with the selected sheet in the control like :"SELECT * FROM ["+Combobox1.Text+"$]"

Answer (score 0):

Pardon me, I went all the way to VBA, since I read the word EXCEL... LOL

Now, to get the list of the existing table in c# you can use
`DataTable schemaTable = conn.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);`

You need conn to be an active connection.

To get the sheets name:

```
foreach (DataRow dr in schemaTable.Rows)
{
    ExcelSheets.Add(dr["TABLE_NAME"].ToString());
}
```

or, using LINQ

```
ExcelSheets = schemaTable.AsEnumerable()
                .Select(r => r.Field<string>("TABLE_NAME"))
                .ToList();
```

Comment: How to get the name of sheets from this datatable for further use?

Comment: @MuhammadRizwan To answer your request I edited my answer

Answer (score 0):

You can put the list of sheets into a DataTable quite easily.

```
DataTable dtSheets = conn.GetSchema("Tables")
```

Comment: What is **"Tables"** for?  I have to change it with my table or what?

Comment: No, that is how to query the sheets. Just add that line (as is) and dtSheets will be filled with the sheet names.

Comment: Ok. How to retrieve the sheet names from this `dtSheets`?

Comment: Simply assign the DataTable as the datasource to a combobox. If you need instruction on that, I'm sure there are many examples on the web. If you need to know the column name containing the sheet names, just set a break point and examine the datatable's columns collection.